# How to get employee information from API?

Tags: angular, api

So I have my department table where I should show some information about the employees that work there

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="main">
<div  class = "details" *ngIf="department">

  <h2 ><span class="name">{{department.name }} {{department.location}}</span>  Details </h2>

      <div class="container">
<div> <span >id: </span>{{department.id}}</div>
         <p>Department name:
           <input [(ngModel)]="department.name" placeholder="name" class="Form"/>
          </p>
       <br>
          <p>Location:
            <input [(ngModel)]="department.location" placeholder="location" class="Form"/>
          </p>
       <br>

      <p> Employee:
       <select [(ngModel)]="department.employee"  class="Form">
         <option *ngFor="let employee of employees" value="{{employee.firstname}}">{{employee.firstname}}</option>
       </select>
     </p>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="average">
 <button class="showDetails" (click) = "Show()">Show Employee Details</button>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="emp">
   <p *ngIf="emp" class="emp"> Employee id: {{ emp.id}} </p>
   <p *ngIf="emp" class="emp"> Employee name: {{emp.firstname}}   {{employee.lastname}}   </p>
  <p *ngIf="emp" class="emp"> Employee gender: {{emp.gender}} </p>
  <p *ngIf="emp" class="emp"> Employee age: {{emp.age}} </p>
   <button class="delete" (click) = "Delete()">Hide</button>
 </div>


<div>
<span class = "backbtn">
                    <button class="btn" (click) = "goBack()">Back</button>
                    </span>
                    <span class = "addbtn">
                    <button class="btn" (click)="save()">Update</button>
 </span>
</div>
</div>


__
</div>
```

And here the actual methods:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Department } from '../department';
import { Employee } from '../employee';
import { DepartmentService }  from '../department.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { EmployeeService }  from '../employee.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-department-detail',
  templateUrl: './department-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department-detail.component.css']
})
export class DepartmentDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  department : Department ;
  employees: Employee[];
  emp: Employee;
  average:number=1;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private employeeService: EmployeeService, private location: Location, private departmentService: DepartmentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.getEmployee();
    this.getEmployees();
    this.getDepartment();
  }

  getEmp(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.employeeService.getEmp(id).
    subscribe(data => this.emp = data);
  }

  getDepartment(): void{
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.departmentService.getDepartment(id).
    subscribe(data => this.department = data);
  }

  goBack(): void{
    this.location.back();
  }
  save(): void {
   this.departmentService.updateDepartment(this.department).subscribe();
   this.goBack();
 }
  getEmployees(): void {
    this.employeeService.getEmps().
    subscribe(employees => this.employees = employees);
  }
  Select(firstname:string){
   if(!firstname){ return; }
firstname = firstname.trim();
   this.employeeService.getEmployeeByName(firstname).subscribe(e => this.emp= e);
 }

  Delete():void{
    this.emp = null;
    this.average = 1;
  }
  Show():void{
    this.Select(this.department.employee);
    this.average = null;
  }
}
```

I believe my problem is in the getEmployees method but I do have no idea how it might be changed in order to make it work. It used to work before the API but now it does not work. Thanks in advance

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Employees } from './mock-employees';
import { Employee } from './employee';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
//import {Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type':  'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  emp : Employee[] = Employees;
  private empReadOne = 'http://*******.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/employee/read_one.php?id=';
  private empRead = 'http://*******.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/employee/read.php';
  private empDelete = 'http://*******.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/employee/delete.php?id=';
  private empSearch = 'http://*******.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/employee/search.php?s=';
  private empAdd = 'http://*******.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/employee/create.php';
  private empUpdate = 'http://*******.hera.fhict.nl/api_Web/employee/update.php';


  getEmp(id:number):Observable<Employee>{
  return this.http.get<Employee>(this.empReadOne + id);
  }
  deleteEmp(id:number):Observable<Employee>{
  return this.http.get<Employee>(this.empDelete + id);
  }
  getEmps():Observable<Employee[]>{
  return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.empRead);
  }
  searchEmps(s: string):Observable<Employee[]>{
  return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.empSearch + s);
  }
  putEmps(emp: Employee):Observable<any>{

  return this.http.post(this.empUpdate,emp,httpOptions);
  }
  postEmps(fname: string, lname: string, age: number, gender: string, department: string ):Observable<any>{

  return this.http.post(this.empAdd,{
        "firstname": fname,
        "lastname": lname,
        "age": age,
        "gender": gender,
        "department": department},
        httpOptions);
  }
  getEmployeeByName(firstname:string) : Observable<Employee>{
  // return of (this.emp.find(employee => employee.firstname === firstname))
   return this.http.get<Employee>(this.empRead)
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.employeeService.getEmps()` is most likely not getting you any results... Can you share the `EmployeeService` code as well?

Comment: I added it to the code

Comment: Uhh, this all looks fine. Besides this line `{{emp.firstname}}   {{employee.lastname}}` which should most likely be like this `{{emp.firstname}}   {{emp.lastname}}` I don't see anything wrong here... I suggest debugging your service because client is looking fine...

Answer (score 0):

To debug this you can look at the result of the HTTP call. First check your browser's network tab, what is the HTTP response? If its 200 then its OK, if its 4xx or 500 then theres a problem with the data being sent or an error server side.

To debug the value being returned by the API just do this:

```
getEmp(): void {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.employeeService.getEmp(id).
  subscribe(data => {
    this.emp = data
    console.log('emp', this.emp)
  });
}
```

And check your browser console to see if the response is as expected.

Also worth doing this:

```
const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
console.log('id', id);
```

To check all is as expected.

Comment: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
department-detail.component.ts:54 emp {id: "5", firstname: null, lastname: null, age: null, gender: null, …}

Comment: It gets my id for the department but not the id,firstname,lastname and so on of the employee

Comment: OK so this basically says that your server is giving a value but the value the server is giving is wrong - looks like a server side issue, unless of course this is not an API response but the service is adding the ID? Can you add the service code for this.employeeService.getEmp(id)

Comment: Well, not really sure.

Comment: In the network tab it will show you what JSON the server is returning, does it look right?

Comment: click on the relevant request, it will show the server response

Comment: {id: "5", name: "BISSINI", location: "Amsterdam"}
id: "5"
location: "Amsterdam"
name: "BISSINI"

Comment: {"id":"5","firstname":null,"lastname":null,"age":null,"gender":null,"department":null}

Comment: ok there you go, your server is returning the wrong data, its a server side issue, fix that first :)

Comment: It makes no sense since the employeeService gets data only from a server where the employee information is stored

Comment: Could be lots of things, maybe there is no employee 5 and this is how the server is handling it. Maybe there is no db connection. You need to debug server side to see what is going on and why when you send a 5 the server is returning rubbish. Unlikely but also worth clearing browser cache in case the response is an old cached response. Just mouse click and hold the refresh button in Chrome for a few secs (make sure the console window is open when you do it) to do a hard reload.

Comment: <div *ngFor="let emps of emp">
   
   <p   class="emp"> Employee id: {{ emps.id}} </p>
   <p  class="emp"> Employee name: {{emps.firstname}}   {{emps.lastname}}   </p>
   <p  class="emp"> Employee gender: {{emps.gender}} </p>
   <p  class="emp"> Employee age: {{emps.age}} </p>


    <button class="delete" (click) = "Delete()">Hide</button>
 </div>

I changed my code to that and it worked.